# Excel to Access file upload

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, excel-formula

I hope everyone is doing great.  I have a question in which I don't know if it's possible or not.

I have some code (which I'll post in a moment) that takes data out of Excel and injects them into a table into Access once a button is pressed in excel.  I am now wondering if there is a way for excel to allow someone to find a file on their computer, hold it, and then upload it into the Access database as well along with all of the other data elements (I know there can be a field in access that holds attachments).  Is this possible to have a button with some code behind it that allows excel to hold a file that the person wants to upload and then using some variation of the code below to also transmit it to the Access database into the proper attachment field that Access has?

Thanks so much for all of your time, I truly appreciate it.

Here's my current code that I've used for a long time:

```
 Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
' connect to the Access database
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\filepath_goes_here\access_database_Name;"
' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open "Plan_Items", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdTable
' all records in a table

On Error GoTo transerror

cn.BeginTrans
r = 14 ' the start row in the worksheet
Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0

    With rs
        .AddNew ' create a new record
        ' add values to each field in the record
        
        .Fields("UserName") = Range("X" & r).Value
        .Fields("BuyerName") = Range("A" & r).Value
        .Fields("PlanYear") = Range("B" & r).Value
        .Fields("Category") = Range("C" & r).Value
        .Fields("RMIType") = Range("D" & r).Value
        .Fields("RMIName") = Range("E" & r).Value
        .Fields("GINS") = Range("U" & r).Value
        .Fields("COGSPlan") = Range("V" & r).Value
        .Fields("KFImpDate") = Range("F" & r).Value
        .Fields("PImpDate") = Range("I" & r).Value
        .Fields("TImpDate") = Range("L" & r).Value
        .Fields("AImpDate") = Range("O" & r).Value
        .Fields("KFProb") = Range("G" & r).Value
        .Fields("PProb") = Range("J" & r).Value
        .Fields("TProb") = Range("M" & r).Value
        .Fields("AProb") = Range("P" & r).Value
        .Fields("KFAnnualized") = Range("H" & r).Value
        .Fields("PAnnualized") = Range("K" & r).Value
        .Fields("TAnnualized") = Range("N" & r).Value
        .Fields("AAnnualized") = Range("Q" & r).Value
        .Fields("DescOfRMISavings") = Range("R" & r).Value
        .Fields("ExplOfPlannedSavingsCalc") = Range("S" & r).Value
        .Fields("ExplainImpDate") = Range("T" & r).Value
        .Fields("UnitsOfMeasure") = Range("Y" & r).Value
        .Fields("KF_CYRealized") = Range("AJ" & r).Value
        .Fields("P_CYRealized") = Range("AK" & r).Value
        .Fields("T_CYRealized") = Range("AL" & r).Value
        .Fields("A_CYRealized") = Range("AM" & r).Value
        .Fields("KF_FollowingYearRealized") = Range("AN" & r).Value
        .Fields("P_FollowingYearRealized") = Range("AO" & r).Value
        .Fields("T_FollowingYearRealized") = Range("AP" & r).Value
        .Fields("A_FollowingYearRealized") = Range("AQ" & r).Value
        .Fields("FOBBox") = Range("Z" & r).Value
        .Fields("IBFBox") = Range("AB" & r).Value
        .Fields("WasteReductionBox") = Range("AD" & r).Value
        .Fields("DMUBox") = Range("AA" & r).Value
        .Fields("OtherBox") = Range("AC" & r).Value
        .Fields("YieldImprovementBox") = Range("AE" & r).Value
        .Fields("AnyCheckBoxYes") = Range("AF" & r).Value
        .Fields("KFConcept") = Range("AR" & r).Value
        .Fields("PConcept") = Range("AS" & r).Value
        .Fields("TConcept") = Range("AT" & r).Value
        .Fields("AConcept") = Range("AU" & r).Value
        .Fields("COGSPlanCheck") = Range("AV" & r).Value
        .Fields("CategoryCheck") = Range("AW" & r).Value
        .Fields("Round") = Range("W" & r).Value
        .Fields("UniqueKey") = Range("AG" & r).Value
        .Fields("UniqueKeyWithOriginalRound") = Range("AH" & r).Value
        .Fields("UniqueKeyWithNewRound") = Range("AI" & r).Value
        .Fields("Hurdles") = Range("AY" & r).Value
        .Fields("Department") = Range("AZ" & r).Value
        
        ' add more fields if necessary...
        
    End With
    r = r + 1 ' next row
Loop
rs.UpdateBatch 'injects full table from excel into access at the same time, eliminating possible errors with inserting certain rows over others
cn.CommitTrans 'makes sure that there were no errors before sending off all of the data

cn.Execute "Plan_Items_Qry_UniqueKey_Update_Plan_Items"
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: If you want my opinion, don't store the file itself, you will only have troubles. Just store the file path and open it on demand in VBA.

Comment: That makes sense.  The problem is that hundreds of people submit items with the template and there really is not a centrally located place to put the file and then ask them to give me a file path.  This also adds an additional process to people that aren't very tech savy.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/move-data-from-excel-to-access-90c35a40-bcc3-46d9-aa7f-4106f78850b4

Comment: Why is Excel used as GUI for data entry? Why would people have to be any more 'tech savvy' for code to store filepath than for code to load file to attachment field? Why is there not a 'centrally located' place for these files?

Comment: Well many people in large/small corporations dont even exactly understand what file paths are. Excel is familiar and easy to click a button and send data to a structured database. Making it where they can just click a button and it opens up and then click the file and it stores it and then they click send all information button and it sends it all to access seems easier than asking them for a file path. Now to your point on centrally located place for the files, that is a point that could be addressed b/c to Kostas more polite comment there always can be problems in Access with stored files.

Comment: You said user needs to 'find file'. How would a user find file without navigating computer folder structure? Storing filepath or loading file into attachment field usually involves same basic process - locate and select file which commonly utilizes FileSystemObject navigation dialog.